# Creating and finding maximum score in a list of students?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am new to stackoverflow and am kind of stuck on my Python assignment.

This is the question:

> Write a program`MaximumScore.py` that receives a student ID, their name, and the score
>   obtained by the student. Output should display maximum score and the student who got the
>   maximum score.

The required output is to look something like this:

```
Enter student id and score: 101, 89.5
Enter student name: Albert
Enter student id and score: 102, 92.5
Enter student name: Bill
Enter student id and score: 103, 95.5
Enter student name: Capa
Enter student id and score: 104, 79.5
Enter student name: Danny
Enter student id and score: 105, 90.5
Enter student name: Edgar

Maximum score: 95.5
Student id: 103
Student name: Capa
```

My question is how do I get the ID and name to print of the guy who got max score? I also have no idea how to get the name list. I feel like I am missing something major here.

This is my code so far:

```
def main():
 idnum = list()
 score= list()
 name=list()
 n =5
 for i in range(int(n)): idnum,score = input("Enter student id and score : ").split(",")

 print "Maximum Score ", max(score)

main()
```

Comment: you should consider of using dict instead of list. then in dict {'id':'score'} you can sort and print score by id. using three lists you won;t be able to connect element of one list with element of other lists

Comment: Perhaps thats what we are supposed to do. I missed two classes and the teacher has been very unhelpful. I know I missed the lecture on list but I wasnt aware there was even such a thing as dict. Thank you!

Comment: @SohebPanjwani dicts are useful, but in this case it's probably not the best - darvak is incorrect that you can't combine lists, that's *exactly* what `zip` does (actually it works on sequences - search "python sequence" for more information there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider of using dict instead of list. then in dict {'id':'score'} you can sort and print score by id. using three lists you won;t be able to connect element of one list with element of other lists.

in this case read python manual about dictionaries. They are really good written manuals.

about dict you can use i.e. `dict={'id':['name','score']}` so key will be student id, and value of this key will be list of name and score. it's easy to navigate on it.

Comment: Yea that makes so much sense now. I was really confused as to how it would even work with three lists but thats all I knew how to do haha.

Comment: if it helps please mark my answer as helpful or that solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Python's `zip` function

```
idnum = []
score = []
name = []
n = 3

for i in range(n):
    id_score = input('Enter student id and score: ').split(',')
    idnum.append(id_score[0])
    score.append(id_score[1])
    name_ = input('Enter student name: ')
    name.append(name_)

save = zip(score,name,idnum)

for x in save:
    if max(score) in x:
        highest = x
        break
print('Maximum score: ' + highest[0])
print('Student id: ' + highest[2])
print('Student name: ' + highest[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better stick with tuples in one list, and finding the `max` value by key from `lambda`.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Student = namedtuple('Student', 'id name score')

def main():
    students = []
    n = 5
    for i in range(n):
        id, score = input('Enter student id and score: ').split(',')
        id = int(id)
        score = float(score)
        name = input('Enter student name: ')
        student = Student(id, name, score)
        students.append(student)
    student_max_score = max(students, key=lambda x: x.score)
    print('Max score: {}'.format(student_max_score.score),
          'Student id: {}'.format(student_max_score.id),
          'Student name: {}'.format(student_max_score.name),
          sep='\n')

main()
```

Comment: This makes alot of sense actually..but I keep getting this error here: Enter student id and score: 123,321
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 9, in main
    id, score = input('Enter student id and score: ').split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @SohebPanjwani updated answer to separate id and score with a single comma, as you showed.

Comment: Oh yea that seemed to do the trick. Thank you so much this helped a ton. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to do this with just lists.

Comment: @SohebPanjwani glad I helped you. Upvote if useful, please.

Answer (score 0):

Wright almost had it - zip is a great tool to use, but you should just use the `max` function:

```
idnum = []
score = []
name = []
n = 3

for i in range(n):
    id, score = input('Enter student id and score: ').split(',')
    idnum.append(id)
    # If you don't convert to float it will
    # sort in ASCII order, which is not what you want
    score.append(float(score))
    name_ = input('Enter student name: ')
    name.append(name_)

highest = max(zip(score,name,idnum))

print('Maximum score: ' + highest[0])
print('Student id: ' + highest[2])
print('Student name: ' + highest[1])
```

Comment: We have not learned zip so I have no idea whats going on haha but the tuples method makes sense. Im just getting this error when I try to run it     Enter student id and score: 123,321
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 9, in main
    id, score = input('Enter student id and score: ').split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: That's because you wrote `split()` instead of `split(',')`. That means that you're splitting on whitespace instead of a comma, so you would need to enter `123 321`.